# Illegal instruction (core dumped) error when running magenta tensorflow

Tags: python, ubuntu, tensorflow, magenta

This is my output from the terminal. Just trying to run a basic example...

```
~$ source activate magenta

(magenta)~$ melody_rnn_generate --config=basic_rnn --bundle_file=~/basic_rnn.mag --output_dir=~/melodies --num_outputs=10 --num_steps=128 --primer_melody="[60]"
Illegal instruction (core dumped)

~$ python --version
Python 2.7.15 :: Anaconda, Inc.

~$ pip list | grep tensorflow
tensorflow                         1.8.0      
tensorflow-tensorboard             1.5.1  

~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

~$ uname -i
x86_64
```

Not sure how to proceed... Thanks in advance. let me know if any more info is needed

Comment: That's caused by some specific `.so` (shared object) file that containing instructions that is being executed not understood by the CPU. Check `dmesg` and see which `.so` file is faulting, and either find a compatible version or recompile it from source using compiler options that are valid for the specific CPU that you have (e.g. compilers may generate code that will work on newer Intel CPUs that isn't supported on older/basic CPU models).

Comment: Ok. its a problem with tensorflow_framework.so. Did a little searching and I guess this version of tensorflow cannot be installed on my puny cpu.... But I need this version for magenta so I guess I will sign up for an account on google cloud or aws or something like that and try again from there. Thank you for your help.

Comment: [Data Science Stack Exchange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/)